# Algorithmic complexity of abi.encodePacked

Tags: solidity, string

What is the algorithmic complexity of repeated string concatenation via `abi.encodePacked`? Specifically, if we have `m` strings `s_i` for `i` in `[1, m]`, each of identical length `n`, is `abi.encodePacked(s_1, s_2, ..., s_m)` in `O(n * m)` or in `O(n * m^2)`.